# hibernate mapping problem

Tags: c#, nhibernate

i have an object named party and three other objects inherit from this object, using hibernate az orm i have a problem with casting the party to ine of these objects. although i'm using not.lazyload() feature, but i see partyProxy want to be casted to department object , not exact party object . so i see:
Unable to cast object of type 'PartyProxybc26f81f729145c49bc14594bb84cb57' to type 'Domain.OrganizationStructure.Department'
this problem wont happen to those 2 other objects which are inherited from party object.
what could be my problem

Answer (score 0):

PartyProxy would be a subclass of Party. You are probably trying to assign it to a variable of type Department. It would be helpful if you share snippets of the code/mapping

Answer (score 0):

here is the code i'm using :

public class AccountabilityMap : ClassMap
    {
        public AccountabilityMap()
        {
            Schema("organizationstructure");
            Not.LazyLoad();
            Id(p => p.Id);

```
        References(p => p.AccountabilityType)
            .Not.Nullable();

        References(p => p.Child)
            .Column("ChildPartyId")
            .Not.LazyLoad()
            .Not.Nullable();

        References(p => p.Parent)
            .Column("ParentPartyId")
            .Not.LazyLoad()
            .Not.Nullable();
    }
}
```

public class PartyMap : ClassMap
    {
        public PartyMap()
        {
            Schema("organizationstructure");

```
        Id(p => p.Id);
```

HasMany(p => p.Children)
                .LazyLoad()
                .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
                .Inverse()
                .KeyColumn("ParentPartyId");

```
        HasMany(p => p.Parents)
            .LazyLoad()
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
            .KeyColumn("ChildPartyId");
```

}
}

public class DepartmentMap : SubclassMap
    {
        public DepartmentMap()
        {

```
        Schema("organizationstructure");
        KeyColumn("PartyId");

        Map(p => p.DepartmentType)
            .Not.Nullable()
            .CustomSqlType("tinyint")
            .CustomType<DepartmentType>()
            .Length(1);

        HasManyToMany(p => p.DepartmentGroup)
            .Table("DepartmentGroupToDepartment")
            .Schema("formation");

   }
}
```

fetching the departments: 
                    _department = Parents //  =====> parents:IList
                        .Where(p => p.AccountabilityType.Id == (int)AccountabilityTypeDbId.ParentDepartmentOfPerson)
                        .Select(p => p.Parent)
                        .Cast()
                        .SingleOrDefault();

Comment: please add this to the original question.